# Is there a "portable" format string syntax for i18n?

Tags: language-agnostic, internationalization, string-formatting

Is there a format string syntax for i18n purposes which meets these requirements?

- implementations are available for multiple programming languages (builtin or library binding). At least C/C++, python.
- is open source and ported onto multiple platforms
- supports permutation of positional arguments (like posix printf with $)
- and/or, even better, supports named arguments
- can be extended for application-defined datatypes

Answer (score 2):

I think the [*Formatting and Parsing* features](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse) of the [**International Components for Unicode** (ICU)](http://site.icu-project.org/) might do the trick for you.

ICU has implementations in C/C++ and for Java, and others supply [ICU bindings for 12 languages](http://site.icu-project.org/related), from Python to Cobol. The ICU license allows "any person ... to deal in the Software without restriction....".  The [`MessageFormat` class](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/messages) should give you the named arguments you want. I haven't tried extending the ICU Formatting classes, but they do have a few abstract base classes you could start from.